# JavaScript beginner troubles with quotation marks

Tags: javascript, variables, type-conversion

I'm trying to learn JS from a book (Beginner JavaScript by Jeremy McPeak), but I'm stuck with this code:

```
<script>
var myString = "56.02 degrees centigrade";

document.write("\"" + myString + "\" is " + parseInt(myString, 10) +
" as an integer" + "<br/>");
</script>
```

The result in html is this: `"56.02 degrees centigrade" is 56 as an integer`.

What I don't understand is not explained in the book - why is this code written as it is? Could someone please explain in layman's terms why do we begin with `"\""` (why not just `\"` since that's escape sequence for double quotes), why after that we have to write `"\"` (shouldn't it be just `\"` if we want closing quotation marks for myString), and why is this written after that: `is "`? Basically, that first part really confused me.

Comment: Do you really have those `*` characters in the code?

Comment: You can use `"` *or* `'` as the string literal quote in JavaScript. So `"\""` can be written as `'"'`. If it *were* written as `"""` that would confuse JavaScript parsing - where does the string *really* end? (`"""` would be parsed as two tokens - `""`,`"` - and thus invalid syntax.) The escape character (`\\`) says "the quote *doesn't end* the string, include it as a quote character *in* the string". This will be covered by any [good] tutorial.

Comment: "Do you really have those * characters in the code?" Of course not, sorry - first time user, I was just trying to emphasize that first part of the code, according to the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript (and most other languages), you write a string by putting a sequence of characters between a pair of quote characters. So a string containing `abc` is written as

```
"abc"
```

If you want one of the characters in the string to be a quote character, you have to escape it, so it won't be treated as the end of the string. So a string containing `abc"def` would be written as:

```
"abc\"def"
```

This is demonstrated in your code where it has

```
"\" is "
```

This is a string that begins with a literal quote followed by the word `is`.

If you want a string containing *only* a quote character, you need to put an escaped quote between the quotes that indicate that you're writing a string:

```
"\""
```

That's what's at the beginning of the concatenation expression in your code.

If you just wrote

```
\"
```

that would be an escaped quote. But since it's not inside quotes, it's not a string -- it's not valid syntax for anything.

In Javascript, there's another option. It allows both single and double quotes to be used to surround a string. So if you have a string containing a double quote, you can put it inside single quotes:

```
'"'
```

You don't need to escape it because the double quote doesn't end a string that begins with single quote. Conversely, if you want to put a single quote in a string, use double quotes as the delimiters:

```
"This is Barry's answer"
```

Comment: This is a very nice explanation. I like how it builds from the basics, adding a piece knowledge with each step.

Answer (score 1):

myString is a string. The function parseInt(string, radix) will parse a string as a integer ([see this for more examples](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)).

The quotes are the way they are so that the output has the quotes displayed. If you don't want the quotes in the output the js could be simplified to:

```
document.write(myString + " is " + parseInt(myString, 10) + " as an integer" + "<br/>");
```

but this wouldn't be as clear in showing how parseInt works.